# sealed class's objects mysteriously becoming null when referenced by other companion object

Tags: kotlin

There is a sealed class :

```
sealed class Alphabet(val name: String) {
  object A : Alphabet("A")
  object B : Alphabet("B")
  object C : Alphabet("C")
  object D : Alphabet("D")
  object E : Alphabet("E")

  companion object {
    val array = arrayOf(A, B, C, D, E)
    val list = listOf(A, B, C, D, E)
  }

  override fun toString(): String {
    return name
  }
}
```

And there is another class with companion object :

```
class AlphabetMap {

  companion object {
    val map = mapOf(
      Alphabet.A to 1,
      Alphabet.B to 2,
      Alphabet.C to 3,
      Alphabet.D to 4,
      Alphabet.E to 5
    )
  }
}
```

And if I want to print array (or list) :

```
class AlphabetTest {

  @Test
  fun printValues() {
    Alphabet.array.forEach { print("$it ") };println()
    Alphabet.list.forEach { print("$it ") };println()
  }
}
```

It correctly print the results :

```
A B C D E 
A B C D E
```

but if I initialize the `AlphabetMap` in the code :

```
class AlphabetTest {

  val m = AlphabetMap()

  @Test
  fun printValues() {
    Alphabet.array.forEach { print("$it ") };println()
    Alphabet.list.forEach { print("$it ") };println()
  }
}
```

The result mysteriously becomes :

```
null B C D E 
null B C D E
```

The first element (A) becomes null

If I define

```
val m = AlphabetMap
```

The result is the same.

If I init AlphabetMap in the function :

```
  @Test
  fun printValues() {
    val m = AlphabetMap()  // or val m = AlphabetMap
    Alphabet.array.forEach { print("$it ") };println()
    Alphabet.list.forEach { print("$it ") };println()
  }
```

The result is the same :

```
null B C D E 
null B C D E
```

but if I init like this :

```
  @Test
  fun printValues() {
    Alphabet.array.forEach { print("$it ") };println()
    val m = AlphabetMap() // or val m = AlphabetMap
    Alphabet.list.forEach { print("$it ") };println()
  }
```

Everything works fine now :

```
A B C D E 
A B C D E
```

If I rewrite the AlphabetMap to

```
class AlphabetMap {
  companion object {
    val map = mapOf(
      //Alphabet.A to 1,
      Alphabet.B to 2,
      Alphabet.C to 3,
      Alphabet.D to 4,
      Alphabet.E to 5
    )
  }
}
```

The result becomes

```
A null C D E 
A null C D E
```

And if AlphebetMap is :

```
class AlphabetMap {
  companion object {
    val map = mapOf(
      Alphabet.E to 5
    )
  }
}
```

The result becomes :

```
A B C D null 
A B C D null
```

What could go wrong ? Is it a bug ? or language feature ?

Environments :
jdk1.8.0_144 , OS X

```
<kotlin.version>1.2.0</kotlin.version>
<kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>1.8</kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>
<kotlin.compiler.incremental>false</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
  <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
  <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
  <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
  <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
  <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
  <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
  <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I suspect this is a variant of the static initialiser order problem in Java.

Comment: @smallufo: pls post your last update as answer, it does not belong in the question.

Comment: @WilliMentzel OK , done.

Comment: @smallufo I removed the answer part from your question +1 +1

Answer (score 11):

Another solution is to define `array` / `list` `by lazy` , which seems solves all issues here.

```
sealed class Alphabet(val name: String) {
  object A : Alphabet("A")
  object B : Alphabet("B")
  object C : Alphabet("C")
  object D : Alphabet("D")
  object E : Alphabet("E")

  companion object {
    val array: Array<Alphabet> by lazy {
      arrayOf(A, B, C, D, E)
    }
    val list: List<Alphabet> by lazy {
      listOf(A , B , C , D , E)
    }
  }

  override fun toString(): String {
    return name
  }
}
```

It works well now.

```
A B C D E 
A B C D E
```

Comment: This really saved me from a lot of headaches

Comment: @smallufo can you explain what was the problem and how it solves it?

Answer (score 7):

The only way to get around this problem is to move the map definition outside the class :

```
val map = mapOf(
  Alphabet.A to 1,
  Alphabet.B to 2,
  Alphabet.C to 3,
  Alphabet.D to 4,
  Alphabet.E to 5
)

class AlphabetMap {
  companion object {

  }
}
```

According to JetBrain's [reply on youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21614#comment=27-2583294) and [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kotlin/comments/7hoytl/kotlin_team_ama_ask_us_anything/dqssfg9/) , this is **As Designed** , no way to solve it.

> The problem of cycles in initialization has no general solution. No
>   matter which exact rules we come up with, if the initializer of the
>   object A accesses object B and the initializer of object B accesses
>   object A, one of them will be able to observe the other in an
>   uninitialized state.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is to break the self referential chains, because it's impossible for the code to initialize properly. You can choose where you would do this exactly.

You can do this by either:

1. changing the definitions of some of the objects, so that they don't reside in the same self referential object
2. Introduce intermediary holder objects that can exist before the self referential object to break the chain implicitly. As was answered above, lazy does just that.

You can get this problem in many cases and libraries as you write code. This is just another case with static instantiation. Remember kotlin instantiates on first object reference, so you can postpone instantiation by hiding behind object references - or even lambdas.